# How do I get Market Cap data for a company using urllib and regex?

Tags: python, regex, urllib

When I run the following:

```
try:
    url = 'http://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/AAPL'

    headers = {}
    headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.27 Safari/537.17'
    values = {'quote': 'aapl'}
    data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
    data = data.encode('utf-8')
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    respData = resp.read()

    marketcap = re.findall(r'<span>(.*?)</span>',str(respData))
    for eachP in marketcap:
        print(eachP)
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
```

Python returns:

```
Menu



Back to top







&amp;
 USD
48,485,528
884.23 B
2.52 ( 1.51%)
1.31
```

I am looking for the 884.23 B value and I tried to get that through adding an index number in the following line.

```
marketcap = re.findall(r'<span>(.*?)</span>',str(respData))[15]
```

Once I do that, python returns this:

```
8
8
4
.
2
3

B
```

But instead of that, I would like the program to return the following:

```
884.23 B
```

Help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just so that you understand what is happening in your code: after using the index, the variable `marketcap` contains the string `884.23 B`. Then, in the for loop you iterate over the characters in the string and print each character in a new line

Comment: Thank you so much, that explains a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[Beautifulsoup](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4)** to scrap a website.

**EX:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("http://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/AAPL")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
for tr in soup.findAll("table", class_="abut_bottom"):
    for td in tr.find_all("td"):
        if td.text == "Market Cap":
            print td.text, td.find_next_sibling("td").text
```

**Output:**

```
Market Cap 884.23 B
```